# Binding Hive table to Java Object

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to map an Hive table into a java object. 
The idea is to do something similar to Hibernate does.

For example.
I have the following columns of the table:

```
| column_name1 | column_name2 |
```

and the java class to bind:

```
class Example implements Serializable{
      String columnName1;
      String columnName2;

// constructor, getters and setters
}
```

When I try to:

```
SparkSessionManager.sc()
                .sqlContext()
                .sql("SELECT * FROM tableName" )
                .as(Encoders.bean(Example.class));
```

It doesn't work. It is trying to find `column_name1` in the class.
Is there way I map the variable into a column name?

I know a workaround => I can put in the select `select column_name1 As columnName1 ...` and this works but it is not pretty.

I am using Spark version 2.3.0

Thanks!

Comment: Spark DataFrames are Java objects natively supported by Spark. Furthermore, [Spark can read from Hive](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets) and map tables into DataFrame objects. Can this approach work for your case? If not, please elaborate. Some more information about Encoders that serialize the Dataframes can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets)